# OpenCV cvtColor() change my image dimensions and have wrong colors

Tags: c++, c, opencv, yuv

I'm using openCV C++ API and I'm trying to convert a camera buffer (YUV_NV12) to a RGB format. However, the dimensions of my image changed (width shrinked from 720 to 480) and the colors are wrong (kinda purple/green ish).

```
unsigned char* myYUVBufferPointer = (something passed as argument)
int myYUVBufferHeight = 1280
int myYUVBufferWidth = 720

cv::Mat yuvMat(myYUVBufferHeight, myYUVBufferWidth, CV_8U, myYUVBufferPointer);
cv::Mat rgbMat;
cv::cvtColor(yuvMat, rgbMat, CV_YUV2RGB_NV12);
cv::imwrite("path/to/my/image.jpg",rgbMat);
```

Any ideas? *(I'm more interested about the size changed than the color, since I will eventually convert it to CV_YUV2GRAY_NV12 and thats working, but the size isn't).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code constructs a single channel (grayscale) image called `yuvMat` out of a series of `unsigned char`s. When you try to -- forcefully -- convert this single channel image from YUV 4:2:0 to a multi-channel RGB, OpenCV library assumes that each row has 2/3 of the full 4:4:4 information (`1 x height x width` for `Y` and `1/2 height x width` for `U` and `V` each, instead of `3 x height x width` for a normal `YUV`) therefore your width of the destination image shrinks to 2/3 of the original width. It can be assumed that half of the data read from the original image comes from unallocated memory though because the original image only has `width x height uchar`s but `2 x width x height uchar`s are read from the memory!

If your `uchar` buffer is already correctly formatted for a series of bytes representing YUV_NV12 (4:2:0 subsampling) in the conventional `width x height` bytes per channel, all you need to do is to construct your original `yuvMat` as a `CV_8UC3` and you are good to go. The above assumes that all the interlacing and channel positioning is already implemented in the buffer. Most probably this is not the case though. YUV_NV12 data comes with `width x height uchar`s of `Y`, followed by `(1/2) width x (1/2) x height of 2 x uchar`s representing `UV` combined. You probably need to write your own reader to read `Y`, `U`, and `V` data separately and to construct 3 single-channel `Mat`s of size `width x height` -- filling in the horizontal and vertical gaps in both `U` and `V` channels -- then use `cv::merge()` to combine those single-channel images to a 3-channel `YUV` before using `cv::cvtColor()` to convert that image using `CV_YUV2BGR` option. Notice the use of `BGR` instead of `RGB`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bee! When I try CV_8UC3, I get a segfault when I call cvtColor() __generic_memcpy() at 0x11d7ba8. So you said I should loop through all the pixels of my buffer, and construct a new 3 single-channel? Why BGR instead of RGB?

Comment: FYI, the crash is happening when i call cvtColor() (or when i call imwrite())

Comment: In OpenCV, the default order of colors in a CV_8U3C image is Blue-Green-Red. `cv::imwrite()` for example expects BGR ordering for color images. segfaults can happen for various reasons so it's very hard to figure out why you get a segfault. Sometimes using debug libs in a release program or vice a versa is the culprit. Your best option is to built each channel separately using CV_8U, pushing each channel into a std::vector<cv::Mat>, and using cv::merge to merge the vector into a single CV_8UC3 image.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that "something passed as argument" does not have enough data to fill 720 lines. With some video cameras, not all three channels are represented using the same number of bits. For example, when capturing video on an iPhone, the three channels use 8-4-4 Bytes instead of 8-8-8. I haven't used this type of a camera with OpenCV, but most likely the problem is here.